# Xamarin.Android - lock app in portrait orientation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to lock my app's view to portrait. 
I've researched and came to this.

```
 [Activity(Label = "SuperBillViewActivity", Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

However, my app does not get locked to portrait view.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set `ConfigurationChanges` AND `ScreenOrientation` on every one of your activities:

```
ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation
ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

`ScreenOrientation`:

Will set the activity's orientation.

`ConfigurationChanges`

Will force that the changes assigned to it will be handled by your Activity's code. In the case of `ConfigChanges.Orientation`, without this assignment, the Android OS will destroy and recreate Activity on `Orientation` changes. Normally this a good thing as your alternative landscape layout will be used, but in this case you want to prevent this re-creation process.

#### Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "Orientation", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```